# What does acquire and release Memory Ordering mean in VarHandle

Tags: java, java-9

What does acquire and release Memory Ordering mean in VarHandle?
I can see the below description but not clear on what it means.

acquire:
Ensures that subsequent loads and stores are not reordered before this access; compatible with C/C++11 memory_order_acquire ordering.

release:
Ensures that prior loads and stores are not reordered after this access; compatible with C/C++11 memory_order_release ordering.

Comment: Related: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, modern CPUs can do an out-of-order execution of instructions to increase the processing speed. However for sychronisation purposes you might want to limit the re-ordering capabilities of the processor. That's what memory barriers are for.

For the purpose of further explanations:

- Load - reads something from memory
- Store - writes something into memory

In JVM you'll find those 4 types of memory barriers:

- `#LoadLoad` - all loads before that barrier need to happen before loads after this barrier
- `#LoadStore` - all loads before that barrier need to happen before stores after this barrier
- `#StoreLoad` - all stores before that barrier need to happen before loads after this barrier
- `#StoreStore` - all stores before that barrier need to happen before loads after this barrier

Acquire memory barrier can be seen as a combination of `#LoadLoad` and `#LoadStore` barriers, while release barrier as `#LoadStore` and `#StoreStore`.

For further explanations have a look at this article: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/